# alternative of unescape function for get length of string

Tags: javascript, escaping

I need to get actual string length of these kinds of URLs "fair-and-handsome-men-instant-fairness-face-wash-50g--%E5%9C%A8%E5%8D%8E%E7%BE%8E%E4%BC%81%E5%A4%84%E5%A2%83%E8%89%B0%E9%9A%BE%EF%BC%8C%E9%A9%AC%E6%96%AF%E5%85%8B%E5%8F%91%E5%8A%A8%E9%AD%85%E5%8A%9B%E6%94%BB%E5%8A%BF%E8%83%BD%E5%90%A6%E5%A5%8F%E6%95%88"

```js
var str =  'fair-and-handsome-men-instant-fairness-face-wash-50g--%E5%9C%A8%E5%8D%8E%E7%BE%8E%E4%BC%81%E5%A4%84%E5%A2%83%E8%89%B0%E9%9A%BE%EF%BC%8C%E9%A9%AC%E6%96%AF%E5%85%8B%E5%8F%91%E5%8A%A8%E9%AD%85%E5%8A%9B%E6%94%BB%E5%8A%BF%E8%83%BD%E5%90%A6%E5%A5%8F%E6%95%88';

console.log(str.length);
```

above code snippt result is 252.

But the actual result should be 120 by using unescape method of javascript. but unfortunately unescape is deprecated but still working. alternative methods working fine but it does not get the actual length.

```js
  var str =  'fair-and-handsome-men-instant-fairness-face-wash-50g--%E5%9C%A8%E5%8D%8E%E7%BE%8E%E4%BC%81%E5%A4%84%E5%A2%83%E8%89%B0%E9%9A%BE%EF%BC%8C%E9%A9%AC%E6%96%AF%E5%85%8B%E5%8F%91%E5%8A%A8%E9%AD%85%E5%8A%9B%E6%94%BB%E5%8A%BF%E8%83%BD%E5%90%A6%E5%A5%8F%E6%95%88';

 console.log(unescape((str)).length);
```

anyone can get the alternative solution for unescape ?
Thanks

Comment: A two second search... - _"Usually, `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` are preferred over `unescape`"_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: @Andreas I tried that too, couldn't figure out how to get the length OP wants, do you have an idea of how it can be utilized to replace his `escape`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp
it says:

> The unescape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use
> decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead.

And `decodeURIComponent` seems to work fine on your example data.

Comment: w3schools got/gets better, but there are still superior resources that don't spent all their resources for SEO -> [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org)

Comment: But neither `decodeURI` nor `decodeURIComponent` can replace `escape` in OP's code to produce the 120 that he wants, at least not from what I tried, can you edit a snippet into your question to demonstrate if you figured out how to use it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok, OP is interested in the length of the UTF-8 encoding of the string, not necessarily the string itself, for that your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match either encoded `%` characters, or any other character:

```js
var str =  'fair-and-handsome-men-instant-fairness-face-wash-50g--%E5%9C%A8%E5%8D%8E%E7%BE%8E%E4%BC%81%E5%A4%84%E5%A2%83%E8%89%B0%E9%9A%BE%EF%BC%8C%E9%A9%AC%E6%96%AF%E5%85%8B%E5%8F%91%E5%8A%A8%E9%AD%85%E5%8A%9B%E6%94%BB%E5%8A%BF%E8%83%BD%E5%90%A6%E5%A5%8F%E6%95%88';
console.log(str.match(/%\w\w|./g).length);
```

No need for decoding or encoding at all (I don't see a way to use `decodeURI` in a way that produces the desirable 120 instead of 72)

Comment: Thank u very much all of you. I expect answer got from @CertainOerformance